# Enable mouse support in the console for applications that feature it in GUI terminals

Tags: console, mouse, aptitude, gpm

Is there some general mechanism missing in text mode consoles but present in GUI terminals that I can enable for mouse-supporting applications? By "general" I mean not per-application (not application-specific). For example, aptitude, finch, w3m, etc. understand clicks in GUI terminals but not in Linux consoles with GPM. They seem to share the same problem.

Since aptitude (etc.) *does* include mouse support (it's just inactive in text mode consoles for some reason), the aptitude case should not be seen as "magically adding a feature that an application doesn't support". I have mouse support in Aptitude in a GUI terminal; I have GPM running on a Linux console; how do I get mouse support in Aptitude in the console?

I think there is a switch between GUI terminals and consoles (a feature that makes the difference). I guess we've all encountered a few more of those GUI/console "switches" (and I have a few more of these questions). A "switch" may affect many applications, thus becoming a broader, system-wide issue, yet the issue itself can be specific, which I hope may validate my question.

If not, for simplicity, we could make this question about aptitude and gpm. Any answer may still be a useful lead. At least it helps me learn more about getting the TTY as mouse-aware as it can get.

My purpose was to make console editing more "natural-feeling", with a special focus on nano and readline. Nano and mc were not a good lead; they are just isolated console workaround cases, not mouse support vs no support cases. Readline turned out to be a more complicated case, so it wasn't as representative as I'd hoped. However, after one gets it to work, it probably hits the same "switch". Mouse reporting events seem to be encoded differently in the console.

Comment: As you surmise, it requires support from the application. There's no such thing as a system-wide setting to magically add a feature that an application doesn't support. Your question needs to focus on the application you're using. (Or the library, such as readline — which neither nano nor aptitude uses.)

Comment: See [how to get MouseMove and MouseClick in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966903/how-to-get-mousemove-and-mouseclick-in-bash)

Comment: @Gilles What else do I need to do before we can reopen this question?

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Gilles It seems it helped that I notified you about my edit. Is there any way to notify the other voters too?

Comment: @hildred Could you read my updated question and see if my clarifications fixed it? Please let me know if there's something else I need to do before you can vote to reopen it. Also, could you help me notify the other voters?

Comment: Many mouse-capable text-mode programs use shift-mousebutton to mean either handle or ignore the mouse button. e.g. some will require shift-button1 to select text (turning off the app's special handling of mouse buttons, leaving it to gpm) while some do it vice-versa.  AFAIK, there's no standard and no way to configure that behaviour universally...it depends on what the program was written to do.

Comment: The one suggested answer is inadequate.  Might as well provide an accurate answer...

Comment: @ThomasDickey Unfortunately, they haven't reopened it yet. It seems to me that the voters didn't read the fixed version. If you could do something about this...

Comment: There are (counting mine) 3 votes to reopen.  If it were reopened, I'd give a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.1.html

`nano -m`

Comment: Thank you. I will upvote your answer as soon as I can. I'm still waiting for more system-wide solutions, including interactive session readline.